# $Y_1, Y_2, ... $ are iid Poisson($\lambda$)

Tags: probability, self-study, maximum-likelihood, poisson-distribution

We observe $Y_1, Y_2, ..., Y_T$ such that $T$ is the first $t\geq 1$ for which $Y_t>0$. Define $Y=Y_T$

(a) Find MLE $\hat{\lambda}$.

(b) What is the relative bias, $[E(\hat{\lambda})- \lambda]/\lambda$.

My attempt

(a) We have $Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_{T-1} = 0$.

So the likelihood function simplifies to $$L(\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^{T} \frac{\lambda^{Y_i} e^{-\lambda}}{Y_i!} = \frac{\lambda^{Y_T} e^{-T\lambda}}{Y_T!}  $$ which leads to $\hat{\lambda} = \frac{Y_T}{T}$.

(b) My main question is on this part on finding $E(\hat{\lambda}) = E(\frac{Y_T}{T})$. I am told that this breaks apart as $$E(Y_T\frac{1}{T}) = E(Y_T)E(\frac{1}{T})= \frac{\lambda}{1-e^{-\lambda}} * [- \frac{1-e^{-\lambda}}{e^{-\lambda}} \log(1-e^{-\lambda})] $$

First question is why are $Y_T$ and $T$ independent? My reasoning is T can be basically any nonnegative integer. But the distribution of $Y_t$ is still Poission($\lambda$) regardless of $T$.

Then why is $E(Y_t) = \frac{\lambda}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$ rather than just $\lambda$?

I figured that $T$~Geom(p). So that $E(\frac{1}{T}) = \frac{-p\log(p)}{1-p}$. But why is this $p=1-e^{-\lambda}$?

*While typing this out, I actually figured out that probability of success $p$ is $p = P(Y_T \neq 0) = 1 - P(Y_T = 0)$. So this part is fine, but I will leave it here for completeness. I am still confused on how the expectation factors.*

Comment: Use the law of iterated expectation, maybe?

Comment: I would get $E(\frac{Y_T}{T})=EE\frac{Y_T}{T}|T)= E(\frac{1}{T}E(Y_T|T))?$ But is it true that $Y_T$ is independent of $T$? So that it factors to  $E(\frac{1}{T})E(Y_T)$

Comment: Given the information in your first sentence, the value of $Y_T$ is non-zero but independent from the value of $T$, as $T$ doesn't care about how many events occurred at that time, but an event occurred or not. Then the first multiplicand will be $E[Y_T|...]$ which will explain the $1-P(Y_T=0)$ in the denominator.

Comment: Ok that I got it. Thanks. So they are independent. And then $Y_T$ is basically a zero-truncated Poisson.

Comment: @PaulG $Y_i = 0$ for $i <T$.

Comment: It seems to me you've all but figured this one out.  Given that your question has been upvoted, you might want to answer it yourself, for record-keeping purposes and to help future users of the site who may have a similar question.